# C Pointer Arithmetic, moving around in memory

Tags: c, pointers

In the code below how come doing `current->next = (char*) current + sizeof(Node);` works but doing `current->next = current + sizeof(Node);` does not work?

I don't know why I have to cast 'current' to a char* instead of leaving it a Node* when they are both the same byte size on my system.

```
// on my system
// sizeof(char*) is 4 bytes
// sizeof(Node*) is 4 bytes
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

    typedef struct Node {
        int data;
        struct Node* next;
        struct Node* prev;
    } Node;

    void* heap = malloc(25 * sizeof(Node));

    Node* head = (Node*) heap;
    head->prev = NULL;
    Node* tail = (char*) head + (24 * sizeof(Node));
    tail->next = NULL;
    Node* current = head;

    int i = 0;
    while (current != NULL) {
        current->data = i;
        if (current != tail)
            current->next = (char*) current + sizeof(Node);
        if (current->next != NULL)
            current->next->prev = current;
        current = current->next;
        i++;
    }

    printf("\n");

    current = head;
    while (current != NULL) {
        printf("%d->", current->data);
        current = current->next;
    }

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Due to pointer arithmetic shouldn't it be `current->next = current + 1;`?

Comment: Yes, e.g. `Node* tail = head + 24;` and `current->next = current + 1;`

Comment: (edit) Remove ALL casts, e.g. `Node* head = heap;` and `current->next = current + 1;` In C a `void` pointer is assignable to and from any type without a cast. Casting only part of the arithmetic expression when assigning to type `Node*`, e.g. `current->next = (char*) current + sizeof(Node);` results in `"initialization from incompatible pointer type"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C, pointer arithmetic operates in units of the pointed-to type. If a pointer has type `char *`, then adding 1 or 2 or 3 to it adjusts it to point to a `char` that is 1 or 2 or 3 elements later in a `char` array. If a pointer has type `Node *`, then adding 1 or 2 or 3 to it adjusts it to point to a `Node` that is 1 or 2 or 3 elements later in a `Node` array.

If `current` points to some `Node` X, then `current + 1` would point to the `Node` that follows X. In contrast, if `sizeof (Node)` is, say, 12 bytes, then `current + sizeof(Node)` points to `Node` that is 12 array elements later than X, so 12•12 = 144 bytes later than X.

In `(char *) current + sizeof (Node)`, `current` is converted to a `char *`. Then pointer arithmetic on this `char *` operates in units of `char`, so `(char *) current + sizeof (Node)` points to 12 bytes after X, which is the distance of one `Node`, so it points to the `Node` after X.

The fact that `sizeof (char *)` and `sizeof (Node *)` are the same in your C implementation is irrelevant. These are the sizes of the pointers, not the sizes of the things pointed to. The pointer arithmetic on `char *` and `Node *` operates in units of `sizeof (char)` and `sizeof (Node)`.

(Incidentally, I write `sizeof (char *)` rather than `sizeof(char *)` to convey the fact that `sizeof` is not a function, and the parentheses do not mark an argument list. Rather, sizeof is an operator, and here the parentheses are used in the C grammar to distinguish a type.)

Comment: This is a good explanation, but the phrase "12 elements later than X" in the 2nd paragraph is potentially confusing, as it is not clear that you are using "element" here to refer to a Node.  (Or, rather, it *is* clear, but only to someone who already understands what you're trying to say.)  Perhaps in the example it would be useful to mention that `current + sizeof(Node) == current + 12 == (char *)current + 144`.  Or maybe just get rid of the specific example completely.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to create double linked list, than why'd you create array of nodes? you created array of 25 nodes, that's not suppose to be linked list.

```
Node* tail = (char*) head + (24 * sizeof(Node));
```

why pointer to char (char*)? You're telling compiler that it is pointing to character, that's deliberate.
Anyway, to point to the last node, you gotta add number of bytes between them which is (24*sizeof(Node)). It's type of character pointer, but you assign to a variable whose type is pointer to Node, so It'll automatically cast to Pointer to Node.

But if you're not telling compiler, than It'll adjust addition into pointer by the size of data which pointer is pointing to, In this case it is Node. Since head is pointer to node, adding one will add sizeof(Node). So simply use,

```
Node* tail = head+24;
```

Since you created a array of nodes, you don't need to create link to next node. But for practicing, current is already pointer to node.
If you're casting it to char which takes 1 byte, than you gotta add number of bytes between two nodes, in this case which is again same sizeof(Node).

```
current->next = (char*) current + sizeof(Node);
```

But if you're not casting it, It is already a pointer to Node, Adding one to it will be equal to adding sizeof(Node).

```
current->next = current + 1;
```

Comment: This does not answer the question that was asked.

Comment: @EricPostpischil First breaking into single byte level, than adding number of bytes is deliberate. I'll just fix that.